# Identify nouns and verbs from JSON

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

Imagine I have a JSON data like following:

```
tasks=[
    {
        "id":17,
        "title":"Browse through the list of books", 
        "how_often":"DO",   
        "how_important_task":"EI",  
        "role":"reader",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id":18,
        "title":"Search for a book",
        "how_often":"DS",
        "how_important_task":"EI",
        "role":"reader",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id":19,
        "title":"Request a book",
        "how_often":"WO",
        "how_important_task":"RI",
        "role":"reader",
        ...
    },
    {
        "id":26,
        "title":"See latest arrivals of the books",
        "how_often":"MO",
        "how_important_task":"LI",
        "role":"reader",
        ...
    }

]
```

I am interested in extracting nouns and verbs from this data, possibly for each task object individually.

1. Is it easier/better to handle on my angular frontend or django backend?
2. Are there any libraries for angular which does something like this?
3. Any libraries for django?

Answer (score 1):

This definitely sounds like a task to be done in the backend. The [Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-syntax) from Google does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Great thanks for the pointer! I won't immediately accept the answer, will wait for few more comments to get in more idea! No offence :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/) (or [GitHub project page](https://github.com/nltk/nltk)). Using Python so it is ideal to use with Django and you will have an open source solution with possibilities to check the code.

On the website there is also a lot of study material including examples and book about NTLK.

Of course because I answer with the Python library, I would prefer using server side solution because Python is more scientific language and I supposed it will be much easier find or use something related to the Python than Javascript. But of course, if you want use API which suggest @bugs there will be an option use Javascript. I don't like a much Google APIs because there is a problem to the future if the Google won't make some money from the API.

You should use more solutions and check the quality of the solutions, then you can decide what works the best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!